# How to replace single digit by same digit followed by punctuation?

Tags: python, regex

I want to replace any single digit by the same digit followed by punctuation (comma ,) using python regex?

```
text = 'I am going at 5pm to type 3 and the 9 later'
```

I want this to be converted to

```
text = 'I am going at 5pm to type 3, and the 9, later'
```

My attempt:

```
match = re.search('\s\d{1}\s', x)
```

I could able to detect them but dont now how to replace by the same digit followed by comma.

Comment: What is the output when you execute your regex?

Comment: `(?<=\b\d)\b` replace with `,`

Comment: What if there is a single digit at the start or end of the string?

Comment: @JvdV are you asking OP or with regards to answers? I've added this scenario to my answer.

Comment: OP =). I kind of want to know if there are edge cases where a lone digit would not need to be replaced.

Comment: @JvdV thanks - wondering the same myself; had to answer both possibilities

Comment: @JvdV it should replace even at the end and begining.

Comment: Raghu, does it make sense to add a comma if the single digit is followed by anything other than a space? Can the single digit be preceded by anything other than a space (e.g., is `'A1'` permitted)? Regardless, you should edit your question to clarify what may come immediately before and after the single digit.

Comment: You could try: `print(re.sub(r'(?:^|\s)\d(?=(?:\s|$))', r'\g<0>,', text))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a word boundary and a capture group to achieve this:

```
import re

text = 'I am going at 5pm to type 3 and the 9 later'
re.sub(r'\b(\d)\b', r"\1,", text)
# => 'I am going at 5pm to type 3, and the 9, later'
```

Comment: Your exact requirements are a little unclear (like, what happens if the number is already followed by punctuation? Or is at the end of the string?) But hopefully that's a good starting point for you.

Comment: `{1}` is redundant

Comment: See my comment on @ctwheels' answer.

Comment: @ctwheels oh yes, whoops!! Updated.

Answer (score 3):

#### Regex #1

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/eXP8uD/1)

```
(?<=\b\d)\b
```

Replace with `,`

How it works:

- `(?<=(?:)\d)` positive lookbehind ensuring the following precedes:

  - `\b` assert position as a word boundary
  - `\d` match a digit
- `\b` assert position as a word boundary

To prevent it from matching locations like `3, a` simply append `(?!,)` to the regex.

---

#### Regex #2

To prevent matching a single digit at the start and end of the string, you can use the following regex:

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/eXP8uD/4)

```
(?<=(?<!^)\b\d)\b(?!$)
```

Same as above regex, but adds following:

- `(?<!^)` ensures the word boundary `\b` that it precedes doesn't match the start of the line
- `(?!$)` ensure the word boundary `\b` that it follows doesn't match the end of the line

You can remove either token if that's not the behaviour you want.

To prevent it from matching locations like `3, a` simply change the negative lookahead to `(?!,|$)` or append `(?!,)` to the regex.

---

#### Regex #3

If `\b` can't be used (e.g. if you have some numbers like `3.3`), you can use the following instead:

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/eXP8uD/2)

```
(?:(?<=\s\d)|(?<=^\d))(?=\s)
```

How it works:

- `(?:(?<=\s\d)|(?<=^\d))` match either of the following:

  - `(?<=\s\d)` positive lookbehind ensuring what precedes is a whitespace character
  - `(?<=^\d)` positive lookbehind ensuring what precedes is the start of the line
- `(?=\s)` positive lookahead ensuring what follows is a whitespace character

---

#### Regex #4

If you don't need to match digits at the start of the string, modify the second regex by removing the second lookbehind as such:

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/eXP8uD/3)

```
(?<=\s\d)(?=\s)
```

---

#### Code

[Sample code](https://tio.run/##DcsxCsMwDAXQ3af4m2wIXUKHQkPn3sGLTURiqG2hqpCc3s3ytien7b3NY5QqXQ3Kzh1YQG@kiq2XtiEZ7lJhHXYKY0ZqK2xnPPBJxkpOr6F8@/6yV/Kv5xJzXEPMNIGmiyM40dLMaxjjDw) (replace regex pattern with whichever pattern works best for you):

```
import re

x = 'I am going at 5pm to type 3 and the 9 later'
r = re.sub(r'(?<=\b\d)\b', ',', x)
print(r)
```

Comment: #1 converts `"type 1, again"` to `"type 1,, again"`.

Comment: You're right, easy fix is to add `(?!,)` to the end of each regex